# Unable to initialise dataTables table: 'undefined is not a function'

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am attempting to use an example dataTables table in my application but am met with an exception when using the standard '[zero configuration](http://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/zero_configuration.html)' initialiser.

- The exception is "Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function"
- Both JQuery and dataTables are present scripts upon executing.
- My HTML is the same as the the example html on the zero configuration page, mentioned above, except I have changed the ID to 'grid' (can provide full HTML if of benefit).

Here is a screenshot of my js in the Chrome Developer Tools:
[image]

Note: Grid.js is being displayed and Site.js only controlling changes to the _Layout page to format the navigation bar.

**EDIT:** To load the jquery and dataTables js files I am using bundles (MVCs BundleConfig.cs). I load the jquery file in the header of my _Layout file which renders the cshtml Grid. At the top of Grid.cshtml I am loading the dataTables.js file. Below are how the bundles are specified:

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/Grid").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/jquery.dataTables.js",
                        "~/Scripts/Grid.js"));
```

Comment: take ur datatable function out of document ready function and place it in simple script tag

Comment: I've attempted this with no change in behaviour. I've also tried to execute the above script from console. Is putting my dataTable initialisation in a document ready function not recommended? I would have thought this was important?

Comment: debug your file loading and dependency of file via inspector tool in chrome or nywhere then tell ok !

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. I am able to hit breakpoints in both required javascript files: jquery and dataTables. I assume this means both files are loaded and ready to be used. According to dataTables these are the only two dependencies.

Comment: Show us how you're loading the .js files

Comment: Updated @ZeeTee. I think that's the info you wanted.

Comment: Those are bundles, how about when it loads in your html document, view source of the minified `/grid?v=` .js file and see if the script is actually loaded.

Comment: Thank you for asking that question @ZeeTee. As I was about to post that they all existed I noticed there was a jquery.js reference at the bottom of the view as well. It was hiding in my _Layout view and thus causing an issue as it existed twice. Resolved!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This exception was being thrown as the JQuery script was being added to the page twice (at the top and bottom) which was causing dataTables to be undefined. If this happens to you, check Source for multiple instances of jquery and ensure there is only one.